# How can I use pagination_class in django-rest-framework for my custom pagination class

Tags: pagination, django-rest-framework

**My pagination Class**

```
class ArticleListPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
```

**My Article View Class**

```
class Article(generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Articles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticlesSerializer
    pagination_class = ArticleListPagination

def get(self, request):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = ArticlesSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am able to use custom pagination class using this

```
def get(self, request):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    page = ArticleListPagination()
    new = page.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)
    serializer = ArticlesSerializer(new, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Is it the proper way to use `ArticleListPagination`? If I have stated in my class that my pagination class is `ArticleListPagination`, why it is not changing the return queryset object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### for django_rest_framework **3.0.x** (or below):

You can extends the `rest_framework.mixins.ListModelMixin` directly, or you imlement the `get` or `list` method similar to that.

Of course `generics.GenericAPIView` is also needed.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        # get_paginaion_serializer will read your DEFAULT_PAGINATION_SERIALIZER_CLASS 
        # or view.pagination_serializer_class 
        # we will talk the two variable later
        serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
    else:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

if you wanna config it "**global**", you can config in your settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_SERIALIZER_CLASS': 'YourCustomPaginationSerializer',
    # ...
}
```

if you just wanna set to the specific view:

the attribute is `pagination_serializer_class` instead of `pagination_class`.

```
class MyView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    pagination_serializer_class = YourCustomPaginationSerializerClass
```

### for django_rest_framework **3.1.x**:

it's a slightly different, you can check the docs first. [3.1 Announcement](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/) , [Pagination Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

You can extends the `rest_framework.mixins.ListModelMixin` directly, or you imlement the `get` method similar to that.

Of course `generics.GenericAPIView` is also needed.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

if you wanna config it "**global**", you can config in your settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination'

    # ...
}
```

if you just wanna set to the specific view:

```
class MyView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    pagination_class = YourCustomPaginationClass
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use your custom pagination in viewset and changed on custom view

pagination.py

```
class OneByOneItems(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
             ('lastPage', self.page.paginator.count),
             ('countItemsOnPage', self.page_size),
             ('current', self.page.number),
             ('next', self.get_next_link()),
             ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
             ('results', data)
         ]))
```

views.py

```
class LectionViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = LectionCourse.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = LectionSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['get'], url_path='get-lections/(?P<pk>[^/]+)')
    def get_lection(self, request, pk):
        self.pagination_class = OneByOneItems
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.queryset.filter(course=pk))
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserCreatorSerializer(many=True)
    project = ProjectSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('id', 'theme', 'author', 'project')


class LectionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    choose_course = CourseSerializer(source='course')

    class Meta:
        model = LectionCourse
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'video', 'preview_description', 'number', 'choose_course')
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use Custom pagination as it will allow you modify your response according to your requirements. This method doesn't require much effort.

Below is my code for this... Hope this will be helpful.

custom_pagination.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomPagination(LimitOffsetPagination):
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response({
        "status": True,
        "code": status.HTTP_200_OK,
        'next': self.get_next_link(),
        'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
        'count': self.count,
        'results': data
    })
```

In your view all you need to do is to call two functions, i-e paginate_queryset and the one you created in your pagination class get_paginated_response. "pagination_queryset" takes queryset as parameter and than pass that result to your serializer, finally call "get_paginated_response" which takes serialized data as parameter and in result return response.

```
page = self.paginate_queryset(query_set)
serializer_class = <Your Serializer>(page, many=True,)
return self.get_paginated_response(serializer_search_user.data)
```

Finally declare your custom serialization class in "settings.py".

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
      'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':'<your_app>.<your_peckage>.custom_pagination.CustomPagination',
      'PAGE_SIZE': 5
}
```

Comment: this was the one answer that showed me how to import the pagination class correctly from the app. thanks!