# Implementing pagination in Django with Oracle database

Tags: django, oracle, django-rest-framework, cx-oracle

I have a project utilizing Oracle as database, and inside the db, they have a view. For that view, I have a Django model like this:

```
class MyOrmModel(models.Model):

    # fields

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'target_oracle_view'
        managed = False
```

The corresponding viewset:

```
class LogRecordNewItemViewSet(ListModelMixin,
                              GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = # ...
    pagination_class = None


    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = MyOrmModel.objects.all()
      
        return qs
```

I use `cx-Oracle==7.3.0` to connect to the target database.
Now my goal is to implement pagination. But when I do so, I run into an error

```
class LogRecordNewItemViewSet(ListModelMixin,
                                  GenericViewSet):
        serializer_class = # ...
        pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
> ended

I have come across [this discussion](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29777?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2), but downgrading Django to version 2.0.6 does not work.
Here are my `requirements.txt` content:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asgiref==3.2.9
CacheControl==0.12.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
cx-Oracle==7.3.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
Django==2.0.6
django-cors-headers==3.4.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
djangorestframework-camel-case==1.2.0
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
ipaddr==2.2.0
lockfile==0.12.2
msgpack==0.6.2
packaging==20.3
pep517==0.8.2
progress==1.5
PyJWT==1.7.1
pyparsing==2.4.6
pytoml==0.1.21
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
sentry-sdk==0.16.2
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.8
webencodings==0.5.1
psycopg2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769902/how-can-i-use-pagination-class-in-django-rest-framework-for-my-custom-pagination

Comment: No, my problem has to do with specific case of Oracle. Not DRF

Comment: Can you set the environment variable DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to the value 24? This will indicate what SQL is being executed and any errors that take place. That should help determine what the source of the problem is.