# Django's Very slow initial execution of select query on remote Oracle 11 database when table contain big blobs

Tags: django, database, oracle, prefetch

I actually understand what is causing the problem but can't  figure out a solution that works with Django.

suppose you are trying to read 10,000 records from oracle database over network, normally that would result in 10,000 network connections being open and closed which causes bad performance.

Oracle's answer to that is to send say 1000 records at once per connection, that significantly improve the speed.

However in my case, each row contains blobs that are 1-2MBs, so trying to prefetch 1000 records means nothing happens until I've downloaded (and kept in memory) 1GB-2GB worth of data.

oracle's  sqlplus provides option to control that, either using the `fast` parameter or issuing `set rowprefetch 10` but I can't find solution that works with Django.

I only want to prefetch 10 records or so

Comment: "suppose you are trying to read 10,000 records from oracle database over network, normally that would result in 10,000 network connections being open and closed which causes bad performance." That is not true. You would open a single network connection and read the data over that. Even if you were using 10,000 `SELECT` statements each returning 1 row you could still do it in a single transaction over the same connection (it would just be much less efficient than 1 `SELECT` returning 10,000 rows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170243/implementing-pagination-in-django-with-oracle-database

Comment: "That is not true. You would open a single network connection", thanks for the correction but this is not the point. The point is that "for whatever reasons" oracle client prefetch large number of rows at once which causes problems to me.

Comment: "Possible duplicate" this absolutely has nothing to do with pagination

Comment: Assuming `rowprefetch` is a system variable like it could be in many other DBMSes, have you tried issuing `SET rowprefetch 10` with e.g. `connection.cursor()`?

Comment: I did, but it gave error. I am assuming it's sqliteplus thing not oracle sql thing. or maybe because I am using old version of oracle DB (version 11)?

Comment: With 1-2MB of LOB data per row, your primary constraint is going to be the # of LOB reads, not the # of rows fetched. For every row fetched, your client has to loop on a read of the LOB at a certain read size until it has read the entire LOB, and that's just for one row. So one row of data could require a great many network round trips. You would need to look into a way to configure your driver to use a larger buffer for the LOB reads so it would need less read operations. That is likely to be different than any prefetch/fetch size setting that controls # of rows.

Comment: If the data needs to be sent to the client then don't store it all in memory; instead read some rows and stream them to the client and then discard the data and repeat. If you are loading the data to process it in python and send a summary to the client then, instead, generate the summary in the database and then you do not need to worry about network transmission times or the size of the data in the middle-tier as the data will never leave the database.

Comment: And I agree iwth MT0, you aren't opening and closing network connections. It's TCP which maintains its connection for the lifetime of the session. But still, lots of round trips can really add up depending on your network latency (ping the database host from the client and multiply by 2 to get a round trip estimate). If you are making millions of round trips, even a 10ms latency can add hours of time.

Comment: Per the [driver doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuningfetch): "Queries that return LOBs and similar types will never prefetch rows, so the prefetchrows value is ignored in those cases."  However you can tune the [`arraysize`](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize) value. Another performance tip with LOBS is to fetch as strings/buffers, not as locators, see the [driver documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings you appear to be referring to are usually related to the database driver and not, typically, to the frameworks above the database driver.

For example, `python-oracledb` has documentation on [Tuning python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-python-oracledb) which includes lots of advice ranging from:

- ensuring that you use connection pooling;
- using bind variables;
- SQL tuning;
- [paginating your queries](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#rowlimit); and
- [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-python-oracledb) including setting the `cursor.arraysize` and `cursor.prefetchrows` settings.

If you want to change how many rows are loaded at in each batch from the database then change `cursor.arraysize` and `cursor.prefetchrows`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49274125/1509264) gives an example of setting the `cursor.arraysize` for Django and Oracle 11g. The value for `prefetchrows` can be set in an [Optional Oracle Client Configuration File](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optclientfiles). However, it will not change the total amount of data that needs to be loaded just the size of each batch that is loaded.

If you want to load less total data then paginate your queries (the Django pagination documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/pagination/)).

Comment: This the answer I was looking for. 
I wanted to know how to set raw size / row prefetch and this is how its done (though it involves patching Django files).
 for some reason its not working though, no matter what raw size I put, the query take forever to bring initial result then its very fast after

Comment: "Forever" for the first batch would indicate that the DB is doing lots of work, perhaps because the table is huge, or you don't have good indexes, or your SQL statement is not optimal.  Check your SQL tuning and schema indexing.

Comment: Note 'prefetching' doesn't work with LOBs but array fetching does.

Comment: thanks for the tips!
Django doesn't use oracledb though it uses cx-oracle

Comment: the query is fast if blob are excluded so I know its not about slow query

Comment: @Ramast `python-oracledb` is the successor to `cx_oracle` and can be used with Django in exactly the same way by just changing the `settings.py`; [see this blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19)

Comment: wow thanks a lot! that helped. also there is no longer need to change Django code to change arraysize as it can also by changed through `oracledb.defaults`. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: FWIW Django 5 has native python-oracledb support so the extra boiler-plate code isn't needed any more